# What is this type of (Greek?) chilli pepper?

Tags: chili-peppers, food-identification, greek-cuisine

The chillies pictured below are fairly common in Greece (particularly the north of the country). They are known as "kafteres" (καυτερές) which roughly translates as "spicy".

[image]

I'd like to have a steady supply of them, however I don't know what they are called outside of Greece. What is the name of this variety, and would it be feasible to grow them in the UK?

Comment: Maybe Serrano peppers? Hard to tell from a picture with so much variety even in one type of pepper.

Answer (score 6):

It's a [Frigitello pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friggitello), although in the states they're called pepperoncini. You can grow any spicy chili pepper in the UK provided you have a greenhouse or maybe a conservatory, otherwise don't bother, it just isn't hot enough.

You can find these types of peppers in any turkish and many asian supermarkets, so no need to grow them.

Comment: In southern England at least outdoor chillies are perfectly sensible, though the absurdly hot varieties don't do so well.  Outdoor sweet peppers can be a little small but still fully ripen.  I grow them most years. (Also some in a greenhouse, some on the windowsill)

Comment: You've had more success than me @ChrisH. I've grown a few chilis on windowsills, smaller varieties work better for that. Little flea chilis are bonsai sized and will melt your head off!

Comment: Apache have been reliable in pots outside in a south facing garden in Bristol, if put out in about May. I'm trying a few other varieties this year.

Comment: The linked article describes them as "sweet" (it mentions a "slight heat" later on), whereas the peppers in question vary from fairly hot to quite hot (sorry I don't know where they'd register on the Scoville scale). However looking at images of frigitello I did come across the Hungarian wax pepper which looks like a better match - anyone come across these before?

Comment: Hungarian wax peppers are mild, I've never gotten much heat from them @Philip. There's a huge variation within varieties though, there are Frigitello which are long and others that are fat, some which have little heat and others which have plenty of bite, it all depends on variation and how/where it's grown.

Comment: @Philip : pepperoncini in the US have a bit of heat to them.  They're not  insanely hot, but they're not a bell pepper.

Answer (score 0):

This is Hungarian Hot Wax pepper. It is harvested green, and used  mostly in the northern Greece. They can be grown in the summer in the UK and the rest of Europe.

Comment: Hungarian wax peppers are wider and generally yellow, not green. Though I suppose if you pick them way earlier than ideal (like they do with poor green bell peppers), you might end up with something like what's in the picture.